# GDB Eclipse not finding Source Files

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gdb, eclipse-cdt

Recently I had a bug with my CDT eclipse application, so I downloaded GDB for debugging. It has brought me a lot of frustration. Finally, I have managed to properly install GDB, however when I try debugging my application, I get this error: No source file named /Desktop/workspace/TopVM/src/ShadowStack.h., as you can see there is an unnecessary . at the end of the path and it causes eclipse to freeze, so I have to force quit it. How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

> as you can see there is an unnecessary . at the end of the path and it causes eclipse to freeze

This is not an unnecessary ., it is simply a full stop in the error message. It comes from GDB, probably this [line](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/linespec.c;h=b2233b92d8d263b941914be243be78ccbb43f10f;hb=HEAD#l1544):

```c
throw_error (NOT_FOUND_ERROR, _("No source file named %s."), filename);
```

To fix the problem it would help if you identified if the problem is GDB or CDT, to do this, you can try running GDB without CDT and see if it freezes.

I assume you have found the following resources on setting up GDB on Mac (as I am guessing you are using?):

http://ntraft.com/installing-gdb-on-os-x-mavericks/

Comment: oh sorry, I seem to have missed setting the correct location for gdb.